# Specify javax.net.ssl.trustStore option on java -jar execution

Tags: java

Is there a way to add -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore option on java -jar execution ? I don't want to set it inside environment variable.
I'm not sure but I've tryed the following script but it doesn't work.

```
java -jar MyClass.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\path\to\CertKeyStore
```

Thank your for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options must go before -jar. From the command line help:

```
java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
```

So it's:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\path\to\CertKeyStore -jar MyClass.jar
```

Comment: “You also need to escape backslashes.”  No, you don’t.  At least, not in Windows.  In fact, you shouldn’t.